# VB.NET 2010 RDLC Subreport "Data retrieval failed for the subreport"

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, rdlc, vb.net-2010

Using VB.NET 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have inherited an application with a RDLC report. I have not used those before.  The report was created and works fine but the originator left out a set of data, a subreport for the "parent" record reported on.

I have tried to add a subreport, point the input parameters of the main to the sub(they use same information). Have the sub use a Dataset that points to a Stored procedure and display the results.

Any attempt to execute (and display) sub report data fails with the message

> Data retrieval failed for subreport....located at....Please check the log files for more information.

Off what/where are the log files located?

I can pass in params and as long as I add a dataset w/a stored procedure, I can see the params if I put on report. If I add the stored procedure ...Nothing. I tried a fix found on internet to create a Copy of the XSD's stored procedure call... but that didn't work either.

Main report works fine without Sub.

Thoughts?

What am I missing?

Shouldn't I be able to add a subreport, link up the parameters and have subreport display related information?

Here is my code to call main report:

```
    Dim adapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim table As New DataTable
    Try
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor


        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath & "\IndividualInterviewerDataReport.rdlc"


        Dim ReportParameters(5) As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter
        ReportParameters(0) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("SurveyName", frmMain.SurveyName)
        ReportParameters(1) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("Interviewer", InterviewerId)
        ReportParameters(2) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("Panel", PanelMonth)
        '
        '
        ReportParameters(3) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("- Version: " + ProductVersion)
        ReportParameters(4) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("PanelYear", PanelYear)
        ReportParameters(5) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("SurveyNbr", frmMain.SurveyNum)

        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(ReportParameters)
        ReportViewer1.ShowPrintButton = True
        ReportViewer1.ZoomPercent = 100

        Me.spInterviewerDataByPanelTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = My.Settings.DBConnection

        Me.spInterviewerDataByPanelTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CodingControlDataSet.spInterviewerDataByPanel, frmMain.SurveyNum, PanelYear, PanelMonth, InterviewerId)

        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm remembering correctly, you'll need to handle the `SubreportProcessing` event of the `LocalReport` object, and set the subreport data there.  You do this by setting a property of the `EventArgs` parameter for the event handler.

Here's some code (adapted from [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.subreportprocessing(v=vs.90).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-4)):

```
'In your report setup code'
AddHandler Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing, _
    AddressOf DemoSubreportProcessingEventHandler

'Event hander
 Public Sub DemoSubreportProcessingEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, _
 ByVal e As SubreportProcessingEventArgs)

    e.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DatasetNameInReport", MyDataTable ))
End Sub
```

Comment: how does that work if I'm using another stored proc as a recordsource not a "mydatatable"?

Comment: OK, you're using a `TableAdapter` to fill a `DataTable` in a `DataSet`, using a stored proc?  Pass the target `DataTable` that you've filled, where I have *MyDataTable*.

Comment: I.e.`New ReportDataSource("DatasetNameInReport", Me.CodingControlDataSet.spOtherStoredProcedureName)`.

Comment: Well that doesn't work for me...when I give it the SP name in the location you specfy, I get an error of "..is a type and cannot be used".   this is so frustrating for me.  Any thoughts

Comment: I'll do my best.  When you execute the `Fill` statement to get the data for the subreport, what is the name of the table you're putting the data in?  In your code snippet in the question, you use `Me.CodingControlDataSet.spInterviewerDataByPanel`.  When you get the subreport data, what are you using?

Comment: Thanks anyway, but I gave up on it completely.   Using the VS level report was too frustrating.  I simply converted the main RPT to an RDL for Server Based, added in a sub report.  Hooked them up deployed it worked.  No fuss.   the Client/VS way was too much of a nightmare, thanks.

Comment: @AnnL. - would you be able to look at this? I'm stuck realy bad similar issue! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168128/adding-subreport-rdlc-into-a-main-report-issue